# Excel VBA security, Run time error 429 active X control, multiple sheets appearing in Microsoft Excel Objects

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I'm a complete novice with VBA, but with the help of GPT been able to create a macro to make a process more efficient in my role.

Essentially, the VBA code takes details from multiple tabs into one summary tab, which is in a format for users to copy and paste into another tool.

the file is sent to external customers, where they fill in the details of various tabs as these are order forms, then sent back to us.

1. Majority of the time it works, however on the odd occasion, we get an error in excel with the red bar to say it's been disabled - i have saved this in a location on our network and it seems to be OK, but not all the time.
2. when the macros enabled themselves, I get a run time error 429 Active X component cannot create an object - when debugging, it highlights Set summary = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("summary")
   but i know this code is absolutely fine.
   I then can see in the project pain, in the MS objects, there seems to be lots of new sheets and an additional workbook, could this be causing the issue and why does this happen?
   for example in my excel sheet i only have tabs with names

OrdersA
OrdersB
OrdersC
OrdersD
OrdersE
Summary
Thisworkbook

but there are additional objects called

Sheet1
Sheet2
Sheet3
Sheet4
Sheet5
Sheet6
Thisworkbook1

it seems like there is a duplicate workbook that has been created in the background? but there is nothing visible or hidden, is this as a result of the file being passed through various places and macro security has messed it up?

for enabling the macro, i have saved in a location

but i dont know why it does it? for example, I cannot open it when the file is attached within an outlook attachment, ie someone attached the email which contains the excel within an email
but it seems to open fine as an attachment in an original email.

for the VBA code run time error, I've absolutely no idea why there are additional objects (excel did have to do some repairing, but removed a couple of formulas)

Comment: Having Macros disabled is a policy thing - speak to your IT department or if you have permissions, change your settings to allow macros to run. If you  have set up a trusted location that will only work for you - every one accessing the workbook will need to do the same
As for the rest of your question, without seeing your code it is impossible to tell where the extra objects are coming from.

Comment: Welcome to the board.  Could you have a read of [ASK] and [MCVE] please.  As @CHill60 said - it would be pretty much impossible to see where your code is going wrong without seeing it.  There's an Edit button at the bottom of your question - could you post the code as text (not an image) so it can be copied and pasted.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.